# Mongodb repair problem

Tags: mongodb, repair, database, nosql

There is a problem about Mongodb.Our version is MongoDB version 1.6.4.

Yesterday I had to kill mongodb process in our 64 bit linux machine.
Then queries were running so long time.

I checked with;

*mongod --repair* or ->db.repairDatabase() command and  I checked repair with

->*db.users.validate();*

the result must be "...."result" : " validate"..." but,

returns : { "errmsg" : "ns not found", "ok" : 0, "valid" : false }

How can I fix this error message ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13591606/1566267

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try check [this comment](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair#comment-159227993). But it can be probably hard to solve problem and it is easier to start over as [suggested here](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/d7a03c9862f91319/d2cb078d656ea82b).

I **suggest** to upgrade mongodb to 1.8.x and start it with **--journal** option. No more repairs should be needed then;)

Comment: Thanks Zap, I tried solutions in your suggested comment link.

Comment: Ok, I upgrade 1.8.4 and start with .../mongod and results are working.Thanks Zap.