# mongoDB 2.2.1 - database not valid

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

When I run `db.users.validate();` in the mongo terminal, I get the reply: `{ "errmsg" : "ns not found", "ok" : 0, "valid" : false }`.

Is this normal? How can I solve it, since `mongod --repair` and `db.repairDatabase()` won't help?

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64, mongoDB x86_64 2.2.1 (clean new install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no collection with such name in database. 
If you try to do this in new database you will get the same error.

Comment: Yes, actually `db.test.validate()` returned `"valid" : true`. That's it. I was confused by the documentation. Thanks!